# How to extract results of webpage script using BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a Python program to scrape the web for Product Names given Product Numbers using BeautifulSoup. I am using this page as an example: http://www.adv-bio.com/search-results/?q=1081 . Ideally, I would extract from this page the string "DAIRY COMPLEX NATURAL", and the URL of that link.

I am just beginning to use BeautifulSoup but so far the closest I have gotten to the tag I am looking for was using soup.find('p') which displayed a script that I do not know how to parse for the results.

I really appreciate any help you all can offer.

EDIT here is the code for the script I believe is holding the info I want:

```
<p><script>// <![CDATA[
    (function () {
        var frameBaseSRC = document.getElementById("results").src;
        var frameQueryString = document.location.href.split("?q=")[1];
        if (frameQueryString != undefined) {
            document.getElementById("results").src = frameBaseSRC + "?q=" + frameQueryString;
        }
    })();
```

// ]]>

My code so far is only:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests("http://www.adv-bio.com/search-results/?q=1081")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup.find('p')
```

which just gave me the script text above.

Sorry if I'm not being clear, I've spent a few hours reading but all the links are purple and I feel I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: @t.m.adam is this clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the network traffic in your browser (Inspect > Network), you'll notice that the search results content is provided via a request to `http://prod.adv-bio.com/SearchResults.aspx?q=1081`
So you can use that url instead.

```
url = "http://prod.adv-bio.com/SearchResults.aspx?q=1081"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find('a', {'id':'SearchGridView_ctl02_hlProdDetails'})
text, link = a.text, a.get('href')
```